# hadoop binary file processing

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

Folks,

We would like to know how to process binary files in hadoop with following format.

Basically we have record in the following format in binary file. There is no separator between records or fields. How to write this using hadoop.

```
Integer(16 bytes) Long(32 Bytes) Byte(1 Byte) Integer(16 bytes)
```

Comment: No separator is necessary since you have length. You'll probably want to look at custom InputFormats and InputSplits.

Comment: Guys any one is having working example code. We are kind of finding it difficult.